# Result of rendering form in Rails has no form tags, only inputs

Tags: javascript, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm rendering a form inside another one, but this new rendered form has no form tags, only inputs and submit.

What can be a problem?

Here's my controller:

```
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
  end
```

Here's the new.js.erb:

```
 $('#customer-form').show();
 $('#customer-form').html("<%= j (render 'form_ajax') %>");
```

Here's the _form_ajax.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @customer, remote: true do |f| %>

... inputs in here ...

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "ОК" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

HTML element to render into:

```
<%= form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
  .. some controls here ..  
  <div id="customer-form" style="display:none;"></div>
  .. some inputs here ..
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "ОК" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML element with id = 'customer-form' where you are  rendering 'form_ajax'?

Comment: @Prity added HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about rails, HTML doesn't let one form inside another. Solved the issue by replacing form out of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying render in new.js.erb to this below :-

```
$('#customer-form').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'form_ajax', locals: {customer: @customer}) %>");
```

Let me know it worked or not. Thanks

Comment: put this in the file  console.log("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'form_ajax', locals: {customer: @customer}) %>");   and post what you see in your browser console.

Comment: Put what? I modified new.js.erb as you suggested.

Comment: Hmm.. I see what I need. Rendered partial with form tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113308/discussion-between-marat-and-sghosh968).